# Capture all Upper Case words after a specific keyword in a string with Regex

Tags: regex

I have text blocks that contain 3-5 word terms that are all Init Caps and start with the same word e.g.:

```
Bla bla bla Startword Otherword1 Otherword2 bla bla
```

or

```
Yada yad Startword Otherword1 yada yada
```

https://regex101.com/r/gB1eP0/5

Is there a way for regex to look for the Startword AND then capture the rest of the following string that are init caps?

Comment: Something like [`Startword((?:\s+[A-Z]\w+)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/yA1nO6/2)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Will fail if there are lowercase words in between. OP's probably looking for [**`(?:Startword|\G(?!\A))[^A-Z\n]*([A-Z]\w+)`**](https://regex101.com/r/yA1nO6/3) with the newer `regex` module.

Comment: @Jan, OPs have not been quite eloquent today, I can't judge. I suggest the simplest approach here, since we do not even know for sure if OP regex is of PCRE flavor.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: At least he linked to a `Python` regex tester in the original question but you're right, we'll wait :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry if it has not been clear today I was trying my best with examples and formatting. FYI the flavor is Python. For now all initcaps with no lc in between is fine I shall test and report back thank you.

Comment: I don't think you need the lookarounds, use a `\b` before `Startword` to match it as a whole word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/gB1eP0/7) might work:

***edit:** Modified to exclude `Copyright`*

`(?<!\S)Startword(?:\s+(?!Copyright(?!\S))[A-Z]\S*){2,4}(?!\S)`

Expanded:

```
 (?<! \S )
 Startword
 (?:
      \s+ 
      (?!
           Copyright 
           (?! \S )
      )
      [A-Z] 
      \S* 
 ){2,4}
 (?! \S )
```

Comment: This seems to work well thank you. I am trying to stop the matching at certain words e.g. 'Copyright' so `Startword Otherword1 Otherword2 Copyright` will only capture `Startword Otherword1 Otherword2`. I've tried introducing (?!Copyright) to no avail. Any follow-up advise appreciated.